# Verilog Vivado UART design : implementation / bitstream issues

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, hdl, vivado

I am currently working on my first-ever Verilog project for my company.
I am a newly minted engineer so my experience is just academical.
Forgive me if my English is not perfect, I'll try to do my best.

I need to implement a UART communication on a Xilinx Virtex-7 FPGA. 
At the moment, I have worked on both the receiver and the transmitter by themselves AND connected to each other generating a loopback communication.
Since we had 1 bit error every 50 or so, they asked me to implement a checksum control inside my unit.

I have previously had troubles with blocking vs nonblocking assignments, solved thanks to the awesome StackOverflow community.

At the moment, when I try to send my packet (10 bytes + a checksum, that I precalculate), my unit seems to receive the content correctly (I linked RX_states to GPIO Leds to check if there was activity), when I send the checksum it activates and send back.... a completely wrong string, except for exactly the first character.

I would like to paste the Whole code here, but it exceed the maximum space allowed, so I will truncate where the code has been debugged as best as possible.

**In particular, at the moment I feel like the issue resides in the Receiver-checksum-buffer chain**

```
module async_receiver(
    input reset,
    input clk,
    input RxD, 
    input Rx_enable, //buf_available from the buffer
    output wire RxD_ready, //data_trigger for the buffer
    output wire [7:0] RxD_data
    //output wire [2:0] Rx_state_scope // data received, valid only (for one clock cycle) when RxD_ready is asserted   
    );
    //functional parameters
    parameter ClkFrequency = 200000000; // 200MHz
    parameter Baud = 9600;
    parameter Oversampling = 16;

    reg RxD_ready_internal;

    assign RxD_ready = RxD_ready_internal;


    //state encoding
    localparam  
    RX_IDLE = 3'b000, 
    RX_START = 3'b001,  
    RX_BITS_1 = 3'b010,
    RX_BITS_2 = 3'b011,
    RX_BITS_3 = 3'b100,
    RX_BITS_4 = 3'b101,
    RX_STOP = 3'b110,
    RX_INIT = 3'b111;

    //support variables
    reg [7:0]  RxD_data_int;  
    reg [2:0] Rx_state; //3 bits for 6 states
    integer cnt_0, cnt_1; //input values for my variables
    integer bit_counter;   //bit counter variable
    integer delay_cnt;
    reg RxD_int;
    integer i; //vector index for output data

    //trigger recognition
    wire START_Trigger;
    StartDetectionUnit SDU ( .clk(clk), .state (Rx_state), .signal_in (RxD), .trigger (START_Trigger));

    //tick gen
    wire OversampledTick;        
    BaudTickGenOvers #(ClkFrequency, Baud, Oversampling) as (.reset(reset), .clk(clk), .trigger(START_Trigger), .tick(OversampledTick)); //generates Bitticks for recognition

    //wire assignments     
  //  assign Rx_state_scope = Rx_state;
    assign RxD_data = RxD_data_int;



    always @(posedge clk) begin


        if (reset) 
            begin
                 RxD_ready_internal <= 0;
                 RxD_int <= 1'b0;
                 RxD_data_int <= 8'b00000000;
                 Rx_state <= RX_IDLE;

            end
            else if (Rx_enable)
                        case (Rx_state)


                        RX_INIT:
                                begin
                                    i <= 0;
                                    delay_cnt <= 0;
                                    bit_counter <= 0;
                                    cnt_0 <= 0;
                                    cnt_1 <= 0;
                                    Rx_state <= RX_IDLE;

                                end


                        RX_IDLE: 
                                begin
                                    //reinitialization after each cycle
                                    RxD_ready_internal <= 0;
                                    RxD_int <= 1'b0;
                                    i <= 0;
                                    delay_cnt <= 0;
                                    bit_counter <= 0;
                                    cnt_0 <= 0;
                                    cnt_1 <= 0;

                                        if (START_Trigger) Rx_state <= RX_START; //when RxD is received as zero during an oversampling tick, it starts the state machine

                                end                                                              


                        RX_START:
                                begin

                                if (OversampledTick)

                                   begin
                                            //initialize the length of the word
                                            bit_counter <= 7;
                                            if (delay_cnt > 17 ) //wait for a bit period + an initial delay to avoid sampling on the edge of the bit --> 16 + 2 ticks 
                                                begin
                                                    delay_cnt <= 0;
                                                    Rx_state <= RX_BITS_1;
                                                end
                                            //if 16 ticks have not passed, it increments the counter and stays in the same state
                                            else begin 
                                                 delay_cnt <= delay_cnt+1;
                                                 Rx_state <= RX_START;
                                                 end
                                   end
                                end     


                        RX_BITS_1:
                                    begin

                                        if (OversampledTick) 
                                        begin

                                            if (delay_cnt < 1 ) //i want to execute the recognition ONLY at soon as I change state not for every wait tick
                                                begin
                                                    RxD_int <= RxD; //copy the received bit into an internal "buffer"
                                                    if (RxD_int == 1) cnt_1 <= cnt_1+1;
                                                    else if (RxD_int == 0) cnt_0 <= cnt_0 +1;
                                                end           
                                            if (delay_cnt > 2) //4 ticks delay
                                            begin
                                                delay_cnt <= 0;
                                                Rx_state <= RX_BITS_2; //wait for a few "baud ticks" so the samples are equally interspaced
                                            end
                                            else begin 
                                                     delay_cnt <= delay_cnt+1; //if the wait time has not been completed it stays in the same state
                                                     Rx_state <= RX_BITS_1;
                                                 end
                                            end
                                        end


                        RX_BITS_2:
                                begin
                                if (OversampledTick) //I think this is the most important thing to verify about actual functionality     
                                    begin
                                        if (delay_cnt < 1) //i want to execute the recognition ONLY at soon as I change state not for every wait tick
                                            begin
                                                RxD_int <= RxD; //copy the received bit into an internal "buffer"
                                   //        $display ("seconda acquisizione avviene al tempo", $time);
                                                if (RxD_int == 1) cnt_1 <= cnt_1+1;
                                                else if (RxD_int == 0) cnt_0 <= cnt_0 +1;
                                            end                
                                        if (delay_cnt > 2) //4 ticks delay
                                        begin
                                            delay_cnt <= 0;
                                            Rx_state <= RX_BITS_3; //wait for a whole "baud cycle"
                                        end
                                        else begin
                                             delay_cnt <= delay_cnt+1;
                                             Rx_state <= RX_BITS_2;
                                             end
                                    end
                                end

                        RX_BITS_3:

                                begin
                                    if (OversampledTick) //I think this is the most important thing to verify about actual functionality     
                                    begin
                                        if (delay_cnt < 1)
                                            begin
                                                RxD_int <= RxD;
                                    //          $display ("terza acquisizione avviene al tempo", $time);
                                                if (RxD_int == 1) cnt_1 <= cnt_1+1;
                                                else if (RxD_int == 0) cnt_0 <= cnt_0 +1;
                                            end                 
                                        if (delay_cnt > 2) //4 ticks delay
                                        begin
                                            delay_cnt <= 0;
                                            Rx_state <= RX_BITS_4; //wait for a whole "baud cycle"
                                        end
                                        else begin
                                             delay_cnt <= delay_cnt+1;
                                             Rx_state <= RX_BITS_3; 
                                             end                       
                                    end
                                end

                        RX_BITS_4:
                                begin
                                if (OversampledTick) //I think this is the most important thing to verify about actual functionality     
                                    begin
                                    if (delay_cnt < 1)
                                        begin
                                            RxD_int <= RxD;
                               //             $display ("quarta acquisizione avviene al tempo", $time);                                  
                                            if (RxD_int == 1) cnt_1 <= cnt_1+1;
                                            else if (RxD_int == 0) cnt_0 <= cnt_0 +1;
                                        end                
                                    if (delay_cnt > 2) //4 ticks delay - one tick dedicated to writing
                                    begin

                                        //WRITE FUNCTION
                                        //after checking whether there were 1s or 0s recognized, I write the appropriate value
                                        //and increment the output index
                                        if (cnt_1 >= 3) 
                                            begin
                                                RxD_data_int[i] <= 1;
                               //                 $display ("OUTPUT_UART bit %b all'indice numero %d al tempo: ", RxD_data[i], i, $time);
                                                i<=i+1;
                                            end

                                        else if (cnt_0 >=3)
                                            begin
                                                RxD_data_int[i] <= 0;
                               //                 $display ("OUTPUT_UART bit %b all'indice numero %d al tempo: ", RxD_data[i], i, $time);
                                                i<=i+1; 
                                            end                                

                                        else begin //error case when neither a 0 nor a 1 is recognized
                                         //   $display ("Frame Error!"); 
                                            Rx_state <= RX_IDLE;
                                                 end   

                                         //END OF THE BYTE DESCRIPTION
                                        if (bit_counter == 0) begin 
                                           delay_cnt <= 0;
                                 //          $display ("Detecto la fine del byte al tempo", $time);
                                           Rx_state <= RX_STOP; 
                                           end   
                                           else begin //modify the RX_BITS variables here instead of an in an iterative state
                                                delay_cnt <= 0;
                                                cnt_0 <= 0;
                                                cnt_1 <= 0;
                                                bit_counter <= bit_counter -1;
                                                Rx_state <= RX_BITS_1;    //i have waited for the correct amount of time but the bit wasn't the last one                              
                                                end

                                    end

                                    else begin //wait case when I have not reached the end of the 16 ticks
                                             delay_cnt <= delay_cnt+1; //delay count
                                           //  $display ("valore del delay_cnt %d al tempo:", delay_cnt, $time);
                                             Rx_state <= RX_BITS_4;   
                                         end 


                                end
                            end

                        RX_STOP: 
                                begin

                                if (OversampledTick) 
                                    begin
                                            RxD_ready_internal <= 1;
                                           // $display ("RX RECEIVED: %b aka %c @t=", RxD_data_int, RxD_data_int, $time);
                                            Rx_state <= RX_IDLE; //wait for a whole "baud cycle"
                                        end

                        end                


                        default: Rx_state <= RX_IDLE;
                        endcase
                    end


endmodule   

module checksum256 (
    input reset,
    input [7:0]data, //RxD_data is the data necessary for checksum
    input enable, //RxD_ready flag enables the checksum
    output reg sum_ok //flag to signal that my operation went correctly [to the control unit and to the transmission buffer unit]
    );

    //21.09 SUM_RESULT_INTERNAL becomes SUM_OK directly

    reg [7:0]sum_value; //counting the sum
    integer m; // count the # of byte till i am inside the control byte    
    reg sum_ok_internal;

   // assign sum_ok = sum_ok_internal;    

always @ (posedge enable or posedge reset) //triggers whenever enable (RxD_ready)signal has a rising edge
       begin
        if (reset) 
            begin
                sum_value = 8'b00000000;
                m = 0;
                sum_ok = 0;
            end
           //11th byte is my control byte
           else if (enable)
                begin if (m == 10) 
                    begin
                    //ROUTINE DI CONFRONTO DELLA SOMMA
                        if (sum_value == data) sum_ok = 1;
                        else sum_ok = 0;
                      //  $display ("checksum_result vale %b al tempo: ", sum_ok, $time);
                            sum_value = 0; //reset the sum value
                            m = 0; //reset the word counter    
                    end
                   else begin
                            sum_value = sum_value + data;
                           // $display ("sum_value vale %b al tempo:", sum_value, $time);
                            m = m + 1;
                            sum_ok =0;

                   end 
              end     
       end

endmodule

module output_Dbuffer (
    input reset,
    input [7:0]input_data, //data coming from the receiver
    input data_trigger, //RxD_ready flag tells me that I can copy the data
    input checksum_trigger, //SUM_OK flag from Checksum unit is the trigger for the output buffer
    input RTS_n, //TX_BUSY flag of the transmitter is my ready to send flag
    input clk, //ck needed for the FSM
    output wire TX_trigger, //TX_START flag of the transmitter now comes from THIS unit instead of Receiver
    output wire [7:0]TX_data, //byte for transmission
    output wire buf_available ,

    output wire [2:0]buf_state_scope
    );

    //internal variables
    reg [7:0] mem[0:9]; //memory init, 10 * 8 bit locations
    integer m, n, i, j ; //M = row [a.k.a. bytes], N = column [a.k.a. single bits]

    reg TX_trigger_int;
    reg [7:0] TX_data_int; 
    reg buf_available_flag;
    reg sum256_ok,  checksum_sent;        
    reg [7:0]checksum_buff ;

    //buffer FSM required variables 
    localparam  //state enumeration declaration
        BUF_IDLE = 3'b000, 
        BUF_START = 3'b001,
        BUF_BYTES = 3'b010,  
        BUF_BUSY = 3'b011,
        BUF_TX_CHECKSUM = 3'b100,
        BUF_INIT = 3'b101;

    reg [2:0] buf_state; //2 bits for 4 states

    //static assignments of OUTPUTS : Transmission Flag and Transmission Data (content)
    assign TX_trigger = TX_trigger_int;
    assign TX_data = TX_data_int;

    //signal for sending outside of the system my buf state bits
    assign buf_state_scope = buf_state;
    //flag to signal if the buffer is available or busy
    assign buf_available = buf_available_flag;


  //Block for copying my input data inside the memory    
    always @(data_trigger or reset)
                begin
                  if (reset)   
                    begin
                        for (n = 0; n < 10; n = n+1) mem [n]= 8'h00;
                        i=0;
                        checksum_buff = 8'h00;
                    end     
                   else if (data_trigger)
                        begin 
                            if ( i < 10) 
                            begin
                                mem[i] = input_data;
                              //  $display ("mem[%d ] vale %b al tempo:", i, mem[i],$time);
                                i = i + 1; //the increment happens at the end of current iteration so it doesn't re-iterate on itself
                            end
                        else 
                            begin
                                checksum_buff = input_data; //copy the checksum inside my buffer
                              //  $display("checksum_buff vale %b al tempo:", checksum_buff, $time);
                                i = 0; //the increment happens at the end of current iteration so it doesn't re-iterate on itself

                                 // for (n = 0; n < 10; n = n+1)
                                // $display ("mem[%d] = %b aka %c", n, mem[n], mem[n]);

                                // $display ("checksum = %b aka %c", checksum_buff, checksum_buff);
                            end
                       end
                end


//Block for continuously checking the checksum flag                                   
   always @(*)
    begin
         sum256_ok =0;
         if (reset) sum256_ok = 0;
         else if (checksum_trigger == 1) sum256_ok = 1;        
         else if (checksum_sent == 1) sum256_ok = 0;

    end    


    //Block for transmitting [here I manage the TX_Data and TX_Trigger functionality]
always @(posedge clk)
        begin
            if (reset)
                begin
                        buf_state <= BUF_INIT;
                        TX_trigger_int <= 0;
                        TX_data_int <= 8'b00000000;
                        buf_available_flag <= 1;        
                end

            else case (buf_state)

                BUF_INIT: 
                    begin
                            buf_state <= BUF_IDLE;
                            checksum_sent <=0;
                            j = 0;
                    end


                BUF_IDLE:
                    begin
                        TX_trigger_int <= 0;
                        TX_data_int <= 8'b00000000;
                        m =0;
                        n =0;
                        j =0; 
                        checksum_sent <=0;
                        if (sum256_ok) 
                            begin
                                //check if the TX is not busy
                                if (RTS_n == 0) buf_state <= BUF_START;
                            end


                    end

                BUF_START:
                        begin
                            TX_trigger_int <=0;

                           // if ((i == 0) || ( (j - i) > 1 ))

                            buf_state <= BUF_BYTES;
                               //     else begin
                                      //  $display ("BUFFER BUSY @time:", $time);
                                //        buf_available_flag <= 0;
                               //         buf_state <= BUF_BUSY;   
                               //     end 
                        end   

                BUF_BYTES:
                            begin

                                //check if the TX is busy
                                if (RTS_n==0) 
                                    begin

                                        if (j > 9) 
                                                begin
                                                    TX_trigger_int <= 0;
                                                    buf_state <= BUF_TX_CHECKSUM;
                                                end
                                        else begin
                                                TX_data_int <= mem[j];
                                             //   $display ("BUFFER: %b -> TX", mem[j]);
                                                TX_trigger_int <= 1;
                                                j <= j+1;
                                                buf_state <= BUF_START;
                                            end
                                    end

                            end

                BUF_BUSY:
                                begin
                                    if (RTS_n == 0)
                                        begin 
                                           // $display ("BUFFER AVAILABLE AGAIN @time:", $time);
                                            buf_state <= BUF_START;
                                            buf_available_flag <= 1;
                                        end

                                end

                BUF_TX_CHECKSUM:
                                begin

                                    if (RTS_n==0) begin
                                            TX_data_int <= checksum_buff;
                                            checksum_sent <= 1;
                                            TX_trigger_int <= 1;
                                            buf_state <= BUF_IDLE;

                                        end
                                end

                        default: buf_state = BUF_IDLE;

                        endcase


        end




endmodule
```

Comment: You will probably have more luck learning to debug in ISIM than hoping someone here will read through your entire code. You know what you expect the state machine to do better than anyone, so it might be immediately obvious just from looking at the waveforms what's going wrong. If it works in simulation, you probably have a timing issue. Also, as an aside, are you synchronizing your RxD line at ahigher level with cascaded flipflops to avoid metastability? That's not relevant right now since you're loopbacking but is important in any asynchronous interface.

Comment: FYI, your `mem` array are inferred level-sensitive latches, that is likely unintentional. There is sequential logic still using blocking statements that should be changed to non-blocking; [refresher reference](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf).

Comment: @Greg coming from VHDL i still have trouble on nonblocking vs blocking: which of the blocks should be absolutely changed to nonblocking?

Comment: @jalalipop i also feel like it should be something timing related. The system works 100% the same (to the point of exact clock cycles and waveforms) in post-synth and post-implementation, but while on the FPGA it transmits strange and unrecognizable chars

Comment: @MicheleMarconi Are you 100% sure the waveforms you're seeing in sim are what you want? The way you describe your issue (first char is correct, followed by garbage) it almost seems like your data frames are getting jumbled. This could happen if you aren't properly sending stop->start bits; I'd check if this is the case but I don't see where your actual clock-by-clock Tx logic is in the code. Try scoping the actual Tx line and comparing it to what you see in simulation. If they are the same, it's possible what you think is correct is actually incorrect.

Comment: @jalalipop That's a possible issue. By going over my post-implementation **timing** simulation, I noticed that the mem is not being initialized correctly, so what my transmitter is sending is not being perceived as incorrect, but just the result of incorrect initialization of its memory. Now I am onto determining whether it is received incorrectly, saved incorrectly, or the result of some impurities in terms of my logic (increments/decrements of indexes as said in the following comment about Always block, etcetc)

Comment: @MicheleMarconi If you're new to HDL programming in general, I HIGHLY recommend only coding clocked processes with nonblocking statements (that is,  only ever using `always @(clk) begin... end` always blocks, and only using  `<=` in them). For combinatorial logic, only use assign statements. I spent the first year of my HDL coding experience like this because it was how I was taught by my employer and it saved me a LOT of headaches as a beginner.

Comment: Since you're doing this work for a company, your best bet is to ask a more senior employee. Unless you're the only hardware engineer there, or nobody knows verilog, then you should ask for help. I once had a job where I didn't ask for help much and it didn't go well. Since that job I've asked as much as possible and in the process learned a few things and also discovered problems in the design (if the 3rd explanation still doesn't make sense, it's probably because the plan is wrong). Also, your company probably doesn't want its code posted online, be careful.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in my comment, `mem` is an inferred level-sensitive latch (for rest of the answer I will use latch for anything level-sensitive, and flop for anything edge-sensitive). Latches are inferred in always blocks that are not edge-triggered (`posedge`/`negedge`) and is not assigned to a deterministic value if all logical branches.

Here is your original logic reformatted with my comments:

```
always @(data_trigger or reset) // <-- poorly inferred latch
begin
    if (reset) // Asynchronous reset because 'reset' is in the sensitivity list
    begin
        for (n = 0; n < 10; n = n+1) mem[n] = 8'h00;
        i = 0;
        checksum_buff = 8'h00;
    end     
    else if (data_trigger) // <-- Also asynchronous
    begin 
        if ( i < 10) 
        begin
            mem[i] = input_data;
            i = i + 1; // <-- as a latch will cause feedback loop on FPGA, will not be detected on in Simulations
        end
        else 
        begin
            checksum_buff = input_data;
            i = 0; // <-- also will cause a feedback loop to 'if(i<10)' in FPGA
        end
    end
end
```

Except for synchronous logic, synthesizers do not look at the sensitivity list. Therefore `input_data` and `i` are actually part of the sensitivity list during synthesis. Simulation does use the sensitivity list, therefore it will ignore changes to `input_data` and `i`. This is a place where simulation and synthesis will mismatch.

`i` is part of the real sensitivity and it is updated on every pass of the always block. This creates an asynchronous feedback will `data_trigger` is high and `reset` is low. If you were to have added `i` to your sensitivity list, your simulation would likely hang from an infinite loop. On FPGA there is a slight propagation delay so you will results of seemingly random data. If you were measuring power you would also see high power consumption in this condition.

If you look through your log files there may be a warning about the asynchronous feedback.

`i` needs to be a flop. `mem` and `checksum_buff` should be flops too. From an eyeball review of your code, it looks like everything is running on the `posedge clk` domain. Therefore I suggest you change the code to:

```
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if (reset)   
    begin
        for (n = 0; n < 10; n = n+1) mem[n] <= 8'h00;
        i <= 0;
        checksum_buff <= 8'h00;
    end     
    else if (data_trigger)
    begin 
        if ( i < 10) 
        begin
            mem[i] <= input_data;
            i <= i + 1;
        end
        else 
        begin
            checksum_buff <= input_data;
            i <= 0;
        end
    end
end
```

With this reset will also be synchronous. If you really want asynchronous reset, change it to `always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)`. If you really want `data_trigger` to be the clocking event (I don't recommend it) then change the `posedge clk` to `posedge data_trigger` ***AND*** replace `else if (data_trigger)` with `else`. Any `posedge`/`negedge` signal referenced in the block is treated as an asynchronous trigger. You have this issue in your `checksum256` module.

Verilog combinational logic should be written in `always @*` or the synonymous `always @(*)`. You will run into code that give a list of signals instead of a literal `*`; don't do that. That style is for legacy Verilog-1995. Since Verilog-2001 `@*`/`@(*)` is the preferred strategy to limit the risk an incomplete sensitivity list. The other thing for proper combinational logic is that each left-hand-side (LHS) signal must be assigned to a determinate value for all possible logic branches. Assigning it to itself doesn't count. Assigning it a determinate value at the top of an always block before an `if` or `case` gives it a default assignment. Combinational logic should be assigned with blocking statements (`=`).

Synchronous logic must be have a clocking trigger `posedge` or `negedge`. Do not reference the clock signal in the body of the of the always block. Up to two additional `posedge` or `negedge` signals can be in the sensitivity list for asynchronous reset/preset, and asynchronous must assign registers to constants. Not all FPGAs support flops with asynchronous reset/preset; some have a limited number. Check the manual for your board. Synchronous logic should be assigned with non-blocking statements (`<=`).

Latches usually should be avoided. Unfortunately they can be unintentionally inferred with what should be combinational logic. A latch happens when not all logical branches assign the signal to a deterministic value. If you need a latch, keep it logic simple and assign with non-blocking.

```
always @* begin
  if (enable) Q <= D;
end
```

If you have SystemVerilog you can be more explicit by replacing `always @*` with `always_comb` and `always_latch`. This way your synthesizer can do a better job warning you about unintentional latches.

---

FYI: Verilog non-blocking was inspired/copied form VHDL. The usage of blocking and non-blocking should be similar between the two.

Comment: I realized that I could "synchronize" everything to clock cycles just at the end of yesterday's work day, and I changed that unit (and another one) to clocked processes. My synthesizer was actually interpreting my flag signals that acted as enables, as different clocks, thus creating bad behaviours in terms of inter-clock domains and similar unwanted effects. I have managed to see the errors my system is making by switching from Functional Simulation to post-implementation **timing** simulation, and I will get going about that. Thanks for your clear and well-rounded reply. much appreciated.

Comment: I get a      WARNING: "C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2017.1\data/verilog/src/unisims/FDSE.v" Line 146: Timing violation in scope /UART_tb/DUT/RX1/as/counter_reg[8]/TChk146_13521 at time 2916544520 ps $setuphold (posedge C,posedge S,(0:0:0),(0:0:0),notifier,set_clk_enable_p,set_clk_enable_p,C_dly,S_dly) 
      multiple times regarding the counter that generates my "ticks" for the Receiver. That might actually confuse the receiver and sample the wrong bits

Comment: I cannot tell where the post-synthesis path maps to your RTL. Either the is more code or your synthesizer didn't preserve the names of module instances and registers. This type of timing violation is typically caused but the the combinational logic's propagation delay being longer than the clock period minus setup and hold times. You can try slowing down the path and/or optimizing the logic on that path.

Answer (score 0):

Edited my checksum block to the following:

```
always @ (posedge clk)
       begin
        if (reset) 
            begin
                sum_value[7:0] <= 8'b00000000;
                m <= 0;
                sum_ok <= 0;
            end
            else if (enable)
                begin if (m == 10) 
                    begin
                        if (sum_value[7:0] == data[7:0]) sum_ok <= 1;
                        else sum_ok <= 0;
                            sum_value[7:0] <= 8'b00000000; //reset the sum value
                            m <= 0; //reset the word counter    
                    end
                   else begin
                            sum_value[7:0] <= sum_value[7:0] + data[7:0];
                           // $display ("sum_value vale %b al tempo:", sum_value, $time);
                            m <= m + 1;
                            sum_ok <= 0;

                   end 
              end     
       end

endmodule
```

now I am received back 10 characters, Always the same 10 characters, which are not the 10 I send. (**partially correct**)

IF and when the checksum I send is not correct, my machine does not transmit (**correct**).
The next part is finding why the memory is initialized with values which are not the ones I desire.
Currently using post-implementation *timing* simulation, which seems to be much more accurate than functional, albeit very slow.

I am dedicating my time to analizing waveforms to see if the receiver is getting every bit (and byte, i.e. char) correctly and if it sends it correctly to the memory, and about what the memory is doing to catch unsent and apparently somewhat random content bytes.